# Order a Django Queryset by how many times it appears in a Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In my Django App i have a model called Room,

```
class Room(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) 
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null = True, blank = True)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='participants', blank = True)  
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In my app, i want to show all the Topics ordered by counting how many rooms have that topic.

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

How can i order them?

In my html file i can get this value by using

```
<span>{{topic.room_set.all.count}}</span>
```

that way i get the number of rooms that have this topic, which is useful, but don't work when using the order_by method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Topic.objects.alias(nroom=Count('room')).order_by('-nroom')
```

Comment: I've tried it and it worked.